# Append georeferenced data from one table to another table in CartoDB

Tags: carto

I have two tables with an identical structure of columns in CartoDB. Both are georeferenced.

I'd like to combine the date of the two tables into one table. In the options menu of CartoDB there is an option 'Append data...', which seems to be not activated.

How to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You could just do

```
insert into table2 select * from table1
```

using the SQL console of the CartoDB editor

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the fields match identically in name and type across the tables you want to append.  Then use the SQL console.

```
INSERT INTO master_database (the_geom, field1, field2, field3, etc)
SELECT the_geom, field1, field2, field3, etc
FROM current_database;
```

jorgeas80 set me on the right track but when I attempted to follow his advice, I got the following error:

```
column "created_at" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type text cartodb
```